# How can I limit TFS Product Backlog Items from moving to done based on passed Test Cases?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

In TFS2012, I am looking for a way to gate the movement of a Product Backlog Item from "Committed" to "Done" based on if there are any passed Test Cases attached to the PBI.  I do not want it to go to done unless there is at least one passed test case (or maybe in the future, all test cases are passed).

Using the Visual Studio WIT editor, I open the Product backlog Item.wit file and edit the transition that moves from "committed" to "Done", but I do not see any way to pick a field that relates to the state of any Test Cases related to that PBI.

In the WIT editor, how do I set a rule on a PBI to limit the movement from "Committed" to "Done" based on if at least one Test Case has passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since test results are not part of the work items this cannot be done through simple work item customization.